# Automapping JSON Object to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created this function

```
public void createNewSomeModel(int appID, JToken token)
    {

        var application_id = token.SelectToken("application_id");
        var something_else = token.SelectToken("something_else");


        _context.SomeModel.Add(new NEWSomeModel
        {
            AppID = appID,
            id = application_id,
            something_else = something_else,
        });

    }
```

This accepts a JSON object, and I retrieve the values using `SelectToken`. I want to change it to a MapperProfile. I've looked up `AutoMapperProfile` and I created this:

```
namespace SomeApp.Mappings
{
    public class AutoMapperSomeModel : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperSomeModel()
        {
            CreateMap<JToken, NEWSomeModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("application_id")))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.something_else, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("something_else")));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the Mapper like this,

```
public void CreateNewSomeModel(int appID, JToken token)
    {
        var SomeModelUpdate = _mapper.Map<NEWSomeModel>(token);
        SomeModelUpdate.AppID = appID;
        // THIS HANDLES ADDING. THIS WORKS WITHOUT THE MAPPERPROFILE
        _context.SomeModelUpdates.Add(SomeModelUpdate);
    }
```

It's able to call it properly, but I'm getting

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

It doesn't seem to get the `application_id` from the `token`. What might be wrong here?

Comment: That’s your db layer not automappers fault

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It was working without the mapperprofile.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to get the application_id from the token. What might be wrong here?" If you set a break point to check the SomeModelUpdate, whether the id property is null or not? I checked your AutoMapper and the profile, the code works well, check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRDMw.png). So, I suggest you could check or share the `token`, might be the application_id is null.